# insert query in pl sql

Tags: sql, vba, insert, sql-insert

I want to insert a username that I got from eviron method in a table. I have used insert query for this

```
insert into tab (userid, reason) 
            values ('"&UserName&"','test')
```

I am getting error in this syntax.Can someone pls help me how to correct it.

Comment: Kindly share whole code and specific error

Answer (score 0):

insert into tab (userid, reason) 
            values ('"+UserName+"','test');

You can modify the query in the VBA as described.